# character recognition issue when parsing xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

When using python to extract contents of a xml file and import into a csv file, I found that some characters cannot be recognised, they were converted to some strange characters, such as é was transferred to Ã©, Ü to Ãœ.

I suspect it was due to the character encoding. Because the XML's text locale is en-GB, in Python I set the NLS_LANG as AL32UTF8.

I tried to apply the decode method to following code but did not work at all.
abstract = i.find('abstract').text

Could anyone shed some lights on this?

Comment: Did you mean recognition? Doesn't «character set» ring any bells with you?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I felt it is related to character set. but no sure how to fix. The reason I use AL32UTF8 is to be consistent with the backend oracle db character settings. The en_GB locale is controlled by vendor and we can't change.